# How to automate login functionality using multiple data in Selenium Pytest?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, pytest

I am a beginner to the Selenium world.
I was just trying to automate my web application using Pytest.
But then, I am not aware of how to check the login functionality using multiple data
for eg; I have to check out the login functionality using

1. valid email, valid password
2. invalid email, invalid password
3. valid email, invalid password
4. those email that has not been registered with our service
   all these conditions. How is that possible? I researched about it and found fixture parameterize. But not sure how to use it correctly.
   I have already written a simple test for login using valid username and password. It works fine. But I have to try out login with multiple test scenarios as well.
   Can anyone please help me with this?

Here is my code for conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(params=["chrome"],scope='class')
def setup(request):
chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(TestData.CHROME_EXECUTABLE_PATH)
chrome_driver.maximize_window()
request.cls.driver = chrome_driver
chrome_driver.implicitly_wait(10)
chrome_driver.get(TestData.BASIC_URL)
yield
chrome_driver.close()
```

Here is my code for test_login.py

```
class TestLogin(BaseTest):

LOGIN_LINK = (By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Log In']")
USERNAME_TXT = (By.ID, "login-email")
PASSWORD_TXT = (By.NAME, "password")
LOGIN_BUTTON = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[value='Log In']")


def do_click(self, locator):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)).click()

def do_send_keys(self, locator, text):
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(locator)).send_keys(text)


def test_login_credentials(self):
    self.do_click(self.LOGIN_LINK)
    self.do_send_keys(self.USERNAME_TXT,TestData.REGISTERED_USERNAME_CRED)
    self.do_send_keys(self.PASSWORD_TXT,TestData.REGISTERED_PASSWORD_CRED)
    self.do_click(self.LOGIN_BUTTON)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your driver and test class are working, you can use [@pytest.mark.parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/parametrize.html) to run the same test method under different conditions. For the `login` scenario, it would be something like:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "user, pass",
    [("valid_user@gmail.com", "12345678"), ("invalid_user@gmail.com", "00000000")],
)
def test_login_credentials(self, user, pass):
    self.do_click(self.LOGIN_LINK)
    self.do_send_keys(self.USERNAME_TXT, user)
    self.do_send_keys(self.PASSWORD_TXT, pass)
    self.do_click(self.LOGIN_BUTTON)
```